# Turning off email notifications for Office 365 Groups

Tags: office-365, azure

We need to start using "unified groups" in Office 365/Azure AD for an intranet project that uses Azure AD as the identitiy provider. We want communication to stay in the platform, and what we don't want is our 200 odd users receiving personal inbox emails every time an event is created in the Calendar for the Office 365 Groups they are members of. Or digest style emails of new documents added to the sharepoint doc library.

Basically ZERO notifications in their personal mailbox. Our intranet platform will do enough notifying as it is.

So as far as I can see, in the O365 Admin Center, there is the "Send copy of group conversations and events to group members" setting - which is off by default.

But when a member is added to the group, the group appears in their Outlook automatically and for the group settings there is this "Follow in Inbox" section which is set to "Only replies to you and events" by default.

See the screenshots below. What is the relationship between these two?

[image: Outlook group settings]   [image: O365 Admin group settings]

Is there a way, using PowerShell or other means, to change the per user setting in Outlook to "No email or events" for all members of existing groups? Or set it as the default setting for all new members of the specific groups? Or better still, a way to turn it off at the whole tenancy in one swift action?

If this is the wrong place to ask, please direct me to the correct SE site.